# Incorrect paragraph in footnote

Tags: footnotes, xltabular

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={160mm,234mm},
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm
 }

\usepackage[X2,T2A,OT2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian,russian.ancient]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{url,indentfirst}
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xifthen}


\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.5\textwidth}


\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{titlefoot}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}

\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\centering\bfseries}{\S~\thesection.}{1em}{}


\titleformat{\subsection}
{\centering}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}

\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{,,#1''}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{X | X }
cell1 & cell2\footnote{par1 par1par1 par1par1par1 par1 par1par1 par1 par1 par1 par1
par1 par1par1 par1par1par1 par1 par1-par1-par1 w par1 par1 par1 w par1par1par1par1par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 www

par2 par2par2par2 par2par2 par2 par2 par2 par2
par2 par2 par2par2 par2 par2-par2-par2 w par2 par2 par2 w par2par2par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 ww
} 
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

It is necessary insert new paragraph in footnote.
Why the code above gives error during compilation:

```
xelatex code.tex
>>>>
Runaway argument?
{par1 par1par1 par1par1par1 par1 par1par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 pa\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@footnotetext was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.118 \end{xltabular}
```

Comment: Do you want a footnote at the bottom of the page or a tablenote at the end of the table?

Comment: Probably splitting the footnote up inot `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` might help if you wsh to keep the paragraph break (empty line).

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to place such footnote with 2 paragraphs inside of table.

Answer (score 2):

The error is a bug in longtable.sty, near the end of the file, where it has

```
\def\LT@p@ftntext#1{%
```

it should be changed to

```
\long\def\LT@p@ftntext#1{%
```

For quick relief, copy longtable.sty from the latex files path to your document directory. Edit it making the change above.

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get a new paragraph in a footnote is to use `\endgraf` rather than a blank line or `\par`.
This is provided directly by TeX, and is recommended in *The TeXbook*.  The `\par` mechanism superimposes a lot of processing that is irrelevant to the simple breaking of a line and indenting the next line, hence the annoying error.

I won't repeat the entire example from the question, just the segment with the two-paragraph footnote.

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{X | X }
cell1 & cell2\footnote{par1 par1par1 par1par1par1 par1 par1par1 par1 par1 par1 par1
par1 par1par1 par1par1par1 par1 par1-par1-par1 w par1 par1 par1 w par1par1par1par1par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 www\endgraf
%
par2 par2par2par2 par2par2 par2 par2 par2 par2
par2 par2 par2par2 par2 par2-par2-par2 w par2 par2 par2 w par2par2par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 ww
} 
\end{xltabular}
```

Answer (score 0):

Long in-text footnotes, especially those that span two or more paragraphs, are of rather dubious value to readers. (I think the following piece of advice is due to the economist Greg Mankiw: "First, banish all non-essential stuff into footnotes. Then, delete the footnotes.")

If you want to stick with the ample footnote material, you could "fix" the issue you've encountered either by replacing the all-blank line with `\\` ("double backslash") or by breaking up the long, two-paragraph footnote into two separate footnotes. The second possibility is illustrated below.

You may want to ask yourself, though, if what you're doing is typographically appropriate. What information is supposed to be conveyed via the footnote(s)? Given that they occur in a table, should the footnotes maybe associated visually with the table and hence be placed at the bottom of the table instead of at the bottom of the page? If that is indeed the case, you may want to consider using the `threeparttable` package and its `\tnote` macro and `tablenotes` environment. This possibility is also explored in the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
% [I've pared down the preamble as much as possible]
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={160mm,234mm},margin=20mm}
\usepackage[english,russian,russian.ancient]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,xltabular}
\usepackage[stable,multiple,bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\textit} % italic footnote markers

\setlength\textheight{8cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{| X | X |}
\hline
cell1 & cell2%
\footnote{par1 par1par1 par1par1par1 par1 par1par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 par1par1 par1par1par1 par1 par1-par1-par1 w par1 par1 par1 w par1par1par1par1par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 www}%
\footnote{par2 par2par2par2 par2par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 par2par2 par2 par2-par2-par2 w par2 par2 par2 w par2par2par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 www}
\\ \hline 
\end{xltabular}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X |}
\hline
cell1 & cell2\tnote{a} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] par1 par1par1 par1par1par1 par1 par1par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 par1par1 par1par1par1 par1 par1-par1-par1 w par1 par1 par1 w par1par1par1par1par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 par1 www

\smallskip % 2nd para of footnote:
par2 par2par2par2 par2par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 par2par2 par2 par2-par2-par2 w par2 par2 par2 w par2par2par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 par2 www 
\end{tablenotes} 
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This method will break global numeration of other footnotes.
And we do not need to split into 2 footnotes.

Why such error do not raise in case of `\begin{tabular}`?

Comment: @111 - If the footnotes are indeed table-specific and thus not "ordinary" footnotes, there's neither a need nor a reason for applying the same numbering system for them. Did you see the part in my answer about using a double-backslash in the argument of `\footnote`?